# List nuget dependencies and their current versions

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have large, complicated solution with dependencies on many nuget packages. I want to find out the current versions of all my nuget dependencies.

At present i have a console application that looks through the source tree, finds all the packages.config files, extracts the relevant information and dumps it to a file. Does nuget have a built in way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet provides a [Get-Package command](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) you can run from the Package Manager Console. It will list the packages and versions that are in the current solution. Example output is shown below:

```
PM> Get-Package

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                      
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                      
CommonServiceLocator           1.3                  The Common Service Locator library contains a shared interface for service l...
MvvmLight                      5.2.0.0              The MVVM Light Toolkit is a set of components helping people to get started ...
MvvmLightLibs                  5.2.0.0              The MVVM Light Toolkit is a set of components helping people to get started ...
Newtonsoft.Json                7.0.1                Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                 
Xamarin.Forms                  1.3.3.6323           Build native UIs for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone from a single, shared C...
Xamarin.Forms                  1.4.4.6392           Build native UIs for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone from a single, shared C...
Xamarin.Insights               1.10.6               Insights for your Apps
```

Note that this requires the NuGet packages to have been restored. The Get-Package command basically looks at the packages directory to find the used NuGet packages. It does not use the packages.config file.